# How can I customize a select drop-down box using CSS?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've tried a few different things but none of them work, I want to make it so that this list of drop down options has a grey color displayed behind it upon hover, however all I get is the default blue background with white text upon hover.
HTML:

```
<select placeholder="Category">
    <option value="AllOpt">All</option>
    <option value="AntiquesOpt">Antiques</option>
    <option value="ArtsCraftsOpt">Art &amp; Crafts</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.form-wrapper select { 
    position:absolute;
    width:147px;
    height:40px;
    padding:7px 5px;
    float:left;
    top:74px;
    left:963px;text-indent:3px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:sans-serif,arial;
    border:2px solid #f9f9f9;
    background:#f9f9f9;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:dodgerblue;
} .form-wrapper select:focus { 
    outline:0;
    background:#f9f9f9;
    color:dodgerblue;
} .form-wrapper select option {
    color:black;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-overflow:none;
    padding-right:15px;
} .form-wrapper select option:hover { 
    background-color:grey;
    color:dodgerblue;
    cursor:pointer 
} .form-wrapper select option:focus { 
    background-color:lightgray;
    color:dodgerblue;
    cursor:pointer
}
```

Can anybody give me some guidance as to where I've gone wrong and how I can achieve the results?

Comment: In the case of needing a custom looking dropdown, most people just make their own with divs and css since select isn't very accepting of customization.

Comment: For what few things you CAN style on a default `select`, check out [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Property_compatibility_table_for_form_widgets#Select_boxes_%28single_line%29) (note: N means natural, T means "requires applicable `-appearance:none;`". Note that eventually, once Shadow DOM and other custom element features are fully implemented on all browsers, you'll be able to fairly easily template your custom DDL widget, and even make its DOM appearance match that of a normal select from Javascript's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Move the class definition into the `select` tag (you may need to rename it or make it another class altogether).

```
<select placeholder="Category" class="form-wrapper">
    <option value="AllOpt">All</option>
    <option value="AntiquesOpt">Antiques</option>
    <option value="ArtsCraftsOpt">Art &amp; Crafts</option>
</select>
```

Swap the html elements and CSS classes, e.g. `select.form-wrapper` instead of `.form-wapper select`

```
select.form-wrapper { 
    position:absolute;
    width:147px;
    height:40px;
    padding:7px 5px;
    float:left;
    top:74px;
    left:963px;text-indent:3px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:sans-serif,arial;
    border:2px solid #f9f9f9;
    background:#f9f9f9;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:dodgerblue;
}
select.form-wrapper:focus { 
    outline:0;
    background:#f9f9f9;
    color:dodgerblue;
} 
select option {
    color:black;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-overflow:none;
    padding-right:15px;
} 
select.form-wrapper option:hover { 
    background-color:grey;
    color:dodgerblue;
    cursor:pointer 
}  select.form-wrapper option:focus { 
    background-color:lightgray;
    color:dodgerblue;
    cursor:pointer
}
```